# Como testar se todos os elementos são tuplos de 2 elementos

Tags: python, tuple

Estou a resolver um exercício que em primeiro lugar tenho de testar se o argumento recebido é um tuplo. Se sim, tenho de testar se todos os seus elementos são tuplos de 2 elementos, em que o 1º é uma string, e o 2º é um inteiro.

Sei que para testar se é tuplo usa-se:

```
isinstance(t[i], tuple)
```

Para testar se 1º elemento é string:

```
isinstance(t[0], str)
```

Para testar se o 2º elemento é inteiro:

```
isinstance(t[1], int)
```

A minha dúvida é: como testo se todos os elementos do tuplo, são tuplos de 2 elementos?

Answer (score 0):

```
def testar(argumento):
    return (
        isinstance(argumento, tuple)
        and all(isinstance(elemento, tuple) 
                and len(elemento) == 2
                and isinstance(elemento[0], str)
                and isinstance(elemento[1], int)
            for elemento in argumento)
    )
```